# Does $f(n) = O(g(n))$ imply $f(h(n)) = O(g(h(n)))$?

Tags: asymptotics

Can we prove the following, or find a counterexample?

> $$f(n) = O(g(n)) \Longrightarrow f(h(n)) = O(g(h(n)))$$

I should figure out whether $\log(n^{\log n}) = O(a^{\log n})$, and this will be facilitated if the above holds.

Comment: @idmean I think this can be posted as an answer.

Comment: @Auberon My comment addressed the original question’s title. It has been edited since and seems to be asking something very different now. (I’ve removed it to avoid any confusion.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume for simplicity that $f(n),g(n)$ both take positive integer values. Then $f(n) = O(g(n))$ iff there exists $C>0$ such that $f(n) \leq Cg(n)$ for all $n$. This implies that for any $h\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, $f(h(n)) \leq Cg(h(n))$ holds for all $n$, and so $f(h(n)) = O(g(h(n)))$.

In the general case, a quick perusal of the definitions shows that if $f(n) = O(g(n))$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} h(n) = \infty$ then $f(h(n)) = O(g(h(n)))$. Indeed, $f(n) = O(g(n))$ means that there exist $N,C>0$ such that $f(n) \leq Cg(n)$ for all $n \geq N$. Now suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty} h(n) = \infty$. In particular, there exists $M>0$ such that $h(n) \geq N$ whenever $n \geq M$. Hence $f(h(n)) \leq Cg(h(n))$ for all $n \geq M$.

Comment: however f(n) = n and g(n) = $n^2$ and h(n) = $e^{-n}$ is a counterexample, but your answer gives a proper situation where the above conclusion is correct.
though you should add an extra constraint: h(n) must be strictly ascending.

Comment: Your function $h$ doesn't map naturals to naturals.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely no. $f(n) = O(g(n))$ is correct by $f(n) = n$ and $g(n) = n^2$. As $f(n) \neq g(n)$, hence, $f(h(n)) \neq g(h(n))$ for $h(n) = n$. By the way, we can find infinitely counterexamples for the statement.

Answer (score 0):

From $f(n)=O\big(g(n)\big)$ we cannot conclude equality between $f$ and $g$. Most simple examples seems is when $f \in O(1)$, which means boundedness of $f$, but, obviously not every bounded function equals $1$.

On other hand, when $h:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ takes infinite values from $\mathbb{N}$, then we can  conclude $f(h(n))=O\big(g(h(n))\big)$ .